# How to show and hide widgets in DockLayoutPanel?

Tags: java, gwt

I have the following layout and want to dynamically show and hide the west panel:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel ui:field="dock">
 <g:west><g:Label text="west" ui:field="west"/></g:west>
 <g:east><g:ToggleButton text="toggle"/></g:east>
 <g:center>center</g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

For show/hide I defined a toggle button. It executes:

```
@UiField
Label west;

@UiField
DockLayoutPanel dock;

    dock.remove(west);
    //or
    dock.addWest(west);
```

I want to keep the content in the center element. When I hide `west`, everything works fine an the `center` content resizes accordingly to take the free space.
When I again hit the `ToggleButton` and execute the `addWest()` method, I get following exception:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: No widget may be added after the CENTER widget
```

How can I add/show the west content again, and make the center content resize accordingly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the api [setWidgetHidden()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html#setWidgetHidden%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20boolean%29) to hide any children in dock panel. This api is available from gwt 2.5 version.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for.